# Python3 show Unicode symbols loaded from Mysql

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8, python-3.6

I have strings (English words + foreign word + emojis) stored in the Mysql DB.

The data is loaded with

`charset = 'latin1'`

Then I preproccess the data with

```
str = str.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
```

After doing so everything looks good except for the Unicode symbols that look like \u'******'

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you give an example of how such a string looks, and how it should look like? And please specify how you "look" at the output (`print` to the terminal, write to file or something else).

Comment: Note: performing `.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')` isn't something you need to do normally, but it's a typical work-around to recover from erroneous encoding from a previous step.

Comment: @lenz, I output the strings on the web form and they look like following "98\ud83d\udc2f\ud83d\udc95Puipui Chan"

Comment: Ok, so this happens inside a server-side script, right? Is this CGI or WSGI (or something else)? Can you update the post with some code that shows all operations that happen to the data (fetching, de-/encoding, writing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use encode/decode, it only adds to your woes.

Your description not clear on the path taken for Emoji.  Were they correctly encoded in UTF-8, but then mangled when stored into a latin1 column in the table?

Or was it something else?

See "Best practice" in [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

If erroneously stored into latin1 column see "CHARACTER SET latin1, but have utf8 bytes in it; leave bytes alone while fixing charset" in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases